# How to group by JSON object using custom Pipes in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I am quite new to Angular 2. So could you please someone help me to create custom Pipe in Angular 2?

I have tried below changes

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupTransactions'})

export class GroupTransactionsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(transactions: Array): Array {

    const grouped = transactions.reduce( (grouping, item) => {
    let month = new Date(item.date).getMonth()+1 ;
      grouping[month] = grouping[month] || [];
      grouping[month].push(
        {
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name, 
          price: item.price
     date: item.date
        }
      );
      return grouping;
    }, {} )
    // 'grouped' is an object with properties keyed on date 
    // and each property value is an array of items

    const result = Object.keys(grouped) 
      .map(key => {
        const val = 
        {
          date: key, 
          items: grouped[key] // can sort here by price or name
        }; 
        return val;
      })
      .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.date - a.date;
    });
    // Object.keys makes an array
    // so now we have an array of objects 
    // each with a date property and an items property
    // which is an array of objects (as shaped above) 
    // and finally sort on date

    return result
  }
}
```

But getting wrong date January 1970 instead of September 2017. Currently we are getting groupby by date but I want it by month. In short, if transaction are placed in different date in same month they they should grouped under September month. So what changes are required to get groupByMoth in custom pipe. So I will get output as below:

```
September 17

product 11     £15.00
product 22     £15.00
19 Sep 2017

product 11     £15.00
product 22     £15.00
17 Sep 2017


    August 17

product 11     £15.00
product 22     £15.00
20 Aug 2017

product 11     £15.00
product 22     £15.00
04 Aug 2017


    July 17

product 33     £10.00
product 44     £20.00

    January 16

product 66     £10.00
product 77     £20.00
```

Could you please help to achieve this?

Comment: Check https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think should do the job, no external libs needed

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupTransactions'})
export class GroupTransactionsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(transactions: Array): Array {

    const grouped = transactions.reduce( (grouping, item) => {
      let month = new Date(item.date).getMonth()+1 ;
      grouping[month] = grouping[month] || [];
      grouping[month].push(
        {
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name, 
          price: item.price,
          date: item.date
        }
      );
      return grouping;
    }, {} )
    // 'grouped' is an object with properties keyed on date 
    // and each property value is an array of items

    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
                        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
                        "November", "December"];

    const result = Object.keys(grouped) 
      .map(key => {
        const val = 
        {
          month: key,
          monthName: monthNames[key-1], 
          items: grouped[key] // can sort here by price or name
        }; 
        return val;
      })
      .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.month - a.month;
    });
    // Object.keys makes an array
    // so now we have an array of objects 
    // each with a date property and an items property
    // which is an array of objects (as shaped above) 
    // and finally sort on date

    return result
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let dateGroup of transactions | groupTransactions">
    {{ dateGroup.monthName }}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of dateGroup.items">
        {{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Richard!! This is really helpful but getting some errors. Can i get working code example?

Comment: No problem. There was a minor bug in the map function until about 10 mins ago when I corrected it. Can't say why, but had to add in `const val = {...}; return val;`

Comment: error in this code------const result = Object.keys(grouped) 
      .map(key => { return 
       {
          date: key, 
          items: grouped[key] // can sort here by price or name
        }; 
      })
      .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.date - a.date;
    });  for date "unreachable code detected" and for items "can not  find name items" Can I get working code example?

Comment: It's working as it stands now (see my comment about correction). I had it working in a Plunker, then Chrome said 'awe snap' and the code disappeared. But take my word for it...

Comment: Yes, Its working now. Thanks again! One more thing, what changes are required if I want to grop transactions by month instead of groping by date?

Comment: Come on Pravin, you should be able to work that one out? See the 3 places where `grouping[item.date]` is used - replace it with `grouping[item.date.month]` or whatever method extracts month from your date field. Don't forget you're going to cross over year boundary at some point, so throw the year in front of the month. You can make it a string or a number, should both work.

Comment: I tried but no luck! Can you please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what you have tried in an edit to the question.

Comment: I am done with editing. Please have a look and correct me what i did wrong. I really appreciate you help.

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look

Comment: First I notice there's a comma missing after `price: item.price`. The month calc looks ok though.

Comment: Pravin, your month calc was good, I've added another suggestion in my answer that uses monthName instead. That way you can display it more easily in the HTML. **Sorry, thats no good as the sort is then wrong.**

Comment: Now should be ok, added monthName to the grouping instead and used your month key.

Comment: "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type" error is showing for monthNames[key-1] in map.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be **lodash** groupBy

```js
console.log(_.groupBy([{
    "id": "1",
    "date": 1505408124000,
    "name": "product 11",
    "price": "£15.00"
  },
  {
    "id": "2321",
    "date": 1505408124000,
    "name": "product 112323232",
    "price": "£12325.00"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": 1505829312000,
    "name": "product 22",
    "price": "£20.00"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "date": 1505838225000,
    "name": "product 33",
    "price": "£10.00"
  }
],  'date'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to achieve this with Angular 2 custom pipe.

Comment: You can put the logic inside a pipe. @ downvoter dare to comment